# How to render custom Grid item property in react component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to render few items for a `Grid` component with custom property. Not sure how to do that in a `React` component with `TypeScript`.

```
export interface IComponentItem {
  width: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

export interface IWrapperProps {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const Wrapper = ({ children }: IWrapperProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={1}
      direction="row"
    >
      {children}
    </Grid>
  );
};

Wrapper.Item = ({ width, children }: IComponentItem) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={width} className={classes.contentContainers}>
      {children}
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

Now when I need to render this in another component, how to pass the `width` for the grid item? Here the width represent the `the number of columns the grid item uses` in `xs`.

```
<Wrapper>
      <Button> <<<<<<<<< this component doesn't have any width prop
        Done
      </Button>

      <Button>
        Cancel
      </Button>
    </Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that it can be done in the following way:

```
<Wrapper>
   <Wrapper.Item width={4}>
      <Button> Done </Button>
   </Wrapper.Item>
   <Wrapper.Item width={8}>
      <Button> Cancel </Button>
   </Wrapper.Item>
</Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a customized button that has width props with high-order-component.

```
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { sizing, compose } from '@material-ui/system';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export const CustomButton = styled(Button)(
    compose(sizing)
);
```

Comment: You can add some other props too like spacing, grid, border, flexbox, etc.

import {
    compose,
    spacing,
    palette,
    border,
    display,
    flexbox,
    positions,
    shadows,
    sizing,
    typography,
    grid,
} from '@material-ui/system';

const CustomButton = styled(Button)(
    compose(grid, spacing, palette, border, display, flexbox, positions, shadows, sizing, typography)
);

Comment: I don't want to create new button component. It's not button that needs sizing.It's the grid item which is already defined in the `Wrapper.Item`. Grid already does the spacing using `xs` prop. I just need to pass the value to it. Are you saying there isn't any other way to do so?